# Grep for string in all files in dir, append output file name to txt if found?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory that contains 2000 files. I need to know which files in the directory contain the string "example" in the file, and output the name of the file to a list.txt file that exists, so I end up with list.txt containing the file names of all files containing"example."

```
#!/bin/bash

files = /dir/*

for f in $files
    do
        if grep -i "example" $f; then
            echo "found"
            echo $f >> ~/list.txt
        fi
done
```

So I want list.txt to contain a list of files with the string "example" in their contents.

I'm not getting the append to happen (list.txt remains empty), but I am getting the echo "found" for the number of instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the directory path in "" marks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

files="/path/to/files/*"
for f in $files
  do
    if grep -i "example" $f; then
    echo "found"
    echo $f >> ~/found.txt
    fi
  done
```

I've just tested the above script and worked each time changing the word grep was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -l` for this purpose: (show only the filename of the matching file):

```
grep -i -l "example" * >>~/list.txt
```

Comment: So get rid of the IF statement?

Comment: @boston_019: yes, indeed, there's no need for it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -i -l 'example' -- * >> ~/list.txt
```

or

```
grep -i -l 'example' ./* >> ~/list.txt
```

Comment: So get rid of the IF statement?

Comment: There's no need for it anymore. And take a look at syntax. Use single quotes in grep.In a double quoted string, you have escaped a character that has no special behavior when escaped. Instead, it's invoking the fallback behavior of being interpreted literally.

Instead of relying on this implicit fallback, you should escape the backslash explicitly. This makes it clear that it's meant to be passed as a literal backslash in the string parameter.